# Using guard to protect a router with verification from server

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-router-guards

Consider the code:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, UrlTree, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { UsersService } from 'src/app/shared/services/users.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UtilService } from 'src/app/shared/services/util.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GuardGuard implements CanActivate {
  checking;

  constructor(
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private utilService: UtilService,

  ) { }


  canActivate(destination: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {


    this.usersService.verifyToken(destination.params.jwt)
      .subscribe(
        (res) => { },
        (error) => { this.handleError(error) })

    return true;
  }


  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error["error"].msg) {
      this.utilService.openSnackBar(error["error"].msg, "x")
      throwError(error);
      return false;

    } else {
      throwError(error);
      return false;
    }
  }

}//end of class
```

The idea is simple: it should go to the server and check if the provide token is correct, if so, allow the access, otherwise, block the access.

With guard, as you may know, I have to return either `true` or `false`. The point is that the guard does not wait for the response!

I have tried to set true or false from their respective responses: if it comes an error, then `false`, otherwise `true`: guard does not allow that since one must return something. I have tried to create a global variable, but it is never updated from within subscribe.

Something that seemed easy became a pain in the a*. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The guard waits for a response. Look at your return types, Observable<boolean> | Promise etc. 
You don't subscribe inside the canActivate function, just the return the Observable and do your mapping to a boolean inside a pipe.

`return this.usersService.verifyToken(destination.params.jwt).pipe(map(isVerified => { return isVerified; // just an example you can also put the code from the handleError function here });`

Comment: you tried putting return true inside your success response ?

Comment: yes, I did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes how I have solved the problem

```
import { Injectable, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, UrlTree, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { UsersService } from 'src/app/shared/services/users.service';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { UtilService } from 'src/app/shared/services/util.service';


import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GuardGuard implements CanActivate {
  checking;

  constructor(
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private utilService: UtilService,

  ) { }


  canActivate(destination: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {


    return this.usersService.verifyToken(destination.params.jwt)
      .pipe(
        map(res => {
          return true;//now I need to handle the success case! :)
        }),
        catchError((error) => {
          // console.log(error.error.msg)
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.error.msg) {
            this.utilService.openSnackBar(error.error.msg, "x")
            return throwError(error);

          } else {
            return throwError(error);
          }
        })
      )
  }
}//end of class
```

Thank you all for jumping in and trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
verifyToken(d):boolean{
  this.usersService.verifyToken(d).subscribe(
    (res) => { return true; },
    (error) => { return false; })
}


canActivate(destination: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | 
Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {


return this.verifyToken(destination.params.jwt);
}
```